# How do I verify which build version of my functions and web api's are deployed on Azure portal?

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have developed the function using `HttpTrigger` and deployed it to `Azure` cloud using the publish method. I have multiple environments like `development`, `test`, and `production`.

Now how do I know which successful build I have deployed on different environments? Basically, how do I manage to version it in the cloud?

The same goes for other `app services` like a web app.

Do I have to push it from `host.json`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Versioning has to be done for your system from your side, Azure has no idea of maintaining version control for your APIs, Apps, etc.

If you have not implemented CI/CD in your organization, try looking out for the features provided by **[`Azure Devops`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/)**

The simplest way to implement versioning in Azure Functions is using **[`endpoints`](https://github.com/fbeltrao/Samples/tree/master/azure-functions-versioning)**. The HttpTrigger Attribute allows the definition of a custom route where you can set the expected version.

Comment: we are not using Azure DevOps right now, we are just regular build agent in TFS

Comment: you can do the 3rd way i mentioned

Comment: some sample or links will help.

Comment: I mean simple straight forward sample step links. My question is simple. Do I see build version in azure portal? lets assume build is pushed from CI/CD and build number is 10.23555.7 , do I see this number any where in portal?

Comment: @kudlatiger No you cannot see anywhere in the portal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197976/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-sajeetharan-msft).

Answer (score 1):

you dont, its up to your ci\cd system to display that information. Azure has no knowledge of the binaries you deploy to webapps\azure functions\etc. same goes for vm's, Azure is not aware of what is going on inside them.

Comment: " ci\cd system to display that information" -  but where?

Comment: what do you mean where? in that system ui

Comment: For example what I'm about to implement is a azure function app configuration called "version" and I'll put the build number in there every time I deploy.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I was able to check:

- Go to your app service
- In the left panel search by App service editor
- Find your DLL
- Download
- Use a decompiler and check the code

[image]